# Howto inject Plexus component into Mojo

Tags: maven-3, plexus

Is it possible to inject a Plexus component into a Mojo.
Here's what I tried but `myComponent` is always `null`.

My Component:

```
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(role = MyComponent.class, hint = "mine")
public class MyComponent {

}
```

My Mojo:

```
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.annotations.Requirement;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Component;

public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Requirement(role = MyComponent.class, hint = "mine", optional = false)
    protected MyComponent myComponent;

    @Component
    protected MavenProject project;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot set parameter using annotations on a maven plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620165/cannot-set-parameter-using-annotations-on-a-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You Java part is correct, but you need to add some sources processing to build of your Maven plugin. This can be achieved by adding the following to your `build` in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-component-metadata</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process-classes</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate-metadata</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```